# Do I automatically follow (edits, comments, etc) to wiki answers I've made that I later made community wiki?

Tags: feature-request, support, community-wiki, follow-post

I think I remember a few times some of my CW answers were edited but I wasn't notified. Not sure. But I guess since there isn't a 'follow' button below such answers, I still do follow them?

If this is not the case, I would like to submit this as a feature request please.

Comment: You probably weren't notified because the edit was too minor to result in a notification. This happens with non-CW answers as well, using the same threshold.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog ok thanks. so now feature request? or do i have to make another post?