# Possible incentive problem since edits bump questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, edits, bump

I posted [Is armageddon more fair in a Vickrey auction? in Chess Stack Exchange](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41579/is-armageddon-more-fair-in-a-vickrey-auction/) on February 9th 2023. It was bumped a year later when someone edited my post on 18th March 2024.

Why doesn't this create some incentive problems?

Some thoughts:

1. I can intentionally create typos or something, so that either I or someone else could edit and bump up my post. There's not necessarily a way to tell if I made an honest mistake or if I'm trying to find a loophole.
2. Or can just be negligent: There's an incentive to not proofread my posts. But of course there's a risk of a closed question.
3. And it's not just dishonest/negligent people thought of as honest, but also honest people thought of as dishonest/negligent.
4. Well, I think the real solution is to not have all edits bump questions. Perhaps require reputation to bump.
5. Perhaps edits (or bumps. See the next paragraph) can be scheduled to appear like on YouTube community posts or video uploads like if I do three edits, then (either option or forced by site), then they'll be bumped but only one edit a day. For example, I do three edits now on the 21st, but then they'll show for each of the next days March 21, 22 and 23.

- 5.1 - It can also vary like the edit can show now but the bump happens later. Or both the edit & bump will happen later. For example, again suppose I do three edits on 21st March, but then they'll bump on 21st, 22nd and 23rd. You can either see the edited versions before they get bumped or see the edited versions only later on.

To use a chess analogy: This reminds me of the 2023 Sinquefield Cup a few months ago where [a player had an incentive to intentionally lose a game](https://youtu.be/owmS6mnhFeg) in a tournament not because of bribery to do match fixing, but because it helps that player with some other overall criterion across multiple tournaments. Like it's [FIDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDE), the international chess federation, itself that causes the incentive problem. The player can intentionally lose and get away with it, i.e., dishonest thought of as honest. Or plays for a win, happens to lose and then is thought to intentionally lose, i.e., honest thought of as dishonest.

Comment: Sounds like brainstorming for potential problems and then trying to brainstorm potential solutions to these potential problems. Has any of this really been an issue large enough to cause a problem? Like, let's look at 1. - are there *really* many people who leave deliberate typos *and* manage to craft them such they are caught days/weeks/months later in order to "trick" other people into bumping their posts? Because that, frankly, sounds like a conspiracy theory to me with no basis in reality.

Comment: My opinion is irrelevant: Has this or has it not been a problem here, on the network? Analogies are not actually relevant when  we need to discuss actual real world problems.

Comment: In the past, too many edits of a post resulted in conversion to Community Wiki, thus preventing any further reputation points gain. This was removed [in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/214543#214543): *"[Stop using community wiki as a reputation denial mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940)"*

Comment: @VLAZ 1 - what's your opinion of my chess analogy? 2 - What's wrong w/ my question? 3 - what about bumps for trivial edits where honest people may be thought of dishonest? eg for questions from long ago w/ accepted answers that had typo's but ok weren't noticed / were understood as typo's.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum 1 - [Does CW post still get bumped from edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374952/do-i-automatically-follow-edits-comments-etc-to-wiki-answers-ive-made-that) 2 - What's wrong w/ my question?

Comment: "*what about bumps for trivial edits where honest people may be thought of dishonest?*" any examples of this happening *a lot*? I can't claim it never happened but I also don't really have any examples. If there are only few isolated incidents, it's really not worth dwelling on them that much.

Comment: @BCLC: There is nothing wrong with the gist of your question.

Comment: @JonCuster oh yeah it's 2023 then 2024. edited. thanks

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum what is wrong with my question except for the gist of my question?

Comment: @VLAZ well that's in practice but in theory?

Comment: In theory it'd be better to not tilt at windmills but tackle real problems.

Comment: Related: *[Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122567/allow-non-bumping-minor-edits-but-review-them-on-review)*

Comment: @BCLC: There is ***nothing*** wrong with your question. Hopefully it is sufficiently clear.

Comment: @VLAZ Related issue: Adding to review queue was only a recent thing. Like you can edit (even if gets bumped) but not necessarily expect the question to be reopened. Surely there wasn't a just a windmill tilt for that feature to come out? Edit: oh wow see the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122567/allow-non-bumping-minor-edits-but-review-them-on-review) of This_is_NOT_a_forum. see

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum great minds think alike. thanks!

Comment: @BCLC that's why I'm asking for examples. Is there or is there not an issue? There *was a huge issue* with edits automatically putting a question into the reopen queue. Hence why it was changed. It wasn't theoretical.

Comment: @VLAZ Well even if it's a ['very seldom' case](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/66164/how-do-filipino-catholics-get-a-church-annulment-when-their-state-marriage-is-va/75655#75655) why not do something about it?

Comment: @BCLC because of [opportunity cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost)

Comment: Regarding your last edit (*The 2024 was for some reason removed*), it's not just "some reason". Your previous edit was rolled back because it was invalid and out of place. Rolling back abort all changes, so even though the change of 2023 to 2024 was correct, it was wiped along with everything else in that invalid edit.

Comment: @VLAZ Actually about the queue, in my extremely humble and probably audacious/temeritous opinion, I was impacted by the lack of a queue in that I was thought of as a dishonest person. Could be happening here too.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Why was it invalid and out of place?

Comment: @BCLC because it is not legit to ask in the question why the question getting downvotes.

Answer (score 9):

If someone determines that you are deliberately bumping posts with trivial edits then they may well report you to a moderator. Moderators can suspend you if they determine you are abusing the system.

Other users may immediately correct your mistakes anyway so you can't control when you get that bump. Maybe it would be within the first few minutes of your question going live and then the bump would just make your new question new again and perhaps not achieve that much.

The thing is if your question can be answered easily then it probably will be whether you bump it or not. If not then bumping it is unlikely to help much. We do have a more powerful way to attract attention to questions that won't get you into any trouble at all - raising a bounty on them.

If edits don't bump questions then spammers will as innocuous questions and edit them to contain spam at a later date and nobody who notices will be able to report it for ages.

You need 15 rep to flag for spam, which doesn't sound like much but most visitors won't have that, they may not even have an account at all.

Comment: "the bump would just make your new question new again"—Worse, the edit will change it from "asked X minutes ago" to "modified X minutes ago", making it not look quite as new (though it will be the most recently active).

Comment: 1 - 'If edits don't bump questions then spammers will as innocuous questions' - well does it have to be all or nothing? 2 -  What's wrong w/ my question? 3 - what about bumps for trivial edits where honest people may be thought of dishonest? eg for questions from long ago w/ accepted answers that had typo's but ok weren't noticed / were understood as typo's.

Comment: @BCLC How is the system to determine "trivial"? What's to stop spammers making multiple "trivial" edits till they get the spam they want?

Comment: @RobertLongson Wait how do you spam if you DON'T bump a question? At least my view of spam is usually bumping like putting something in someone's vision.

Comment: you'd create hundreds of thousands of innocuous posts, edit them all without bumping and then someone's bound to come across one of them just from a web search and by the time we figure it out we'd have a hard time deleting them all.

Comment: @RobertLongson 5 - specifically what exactly would benefit is there to edit without bumping? 6 - idea: how about timeline/homepage filter: show all edits, show only major edits, show only trivial edits ?

Comment: 5. I think there is no benefit. 6. I think a filter would be a fine idea - ask **another** feature-request question and suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

The 'incentive' to intentionally & secretly include typos in your posts in order to have them bumped is weak, for a couple reasons.

There are many editors who will quickly correct your typos thus 'bumping' the question only happens **once** and while the question is already near the top of the homepage anyway. If no one notices them and you edit them later, you still only get **one*** bump, which, depending on the activity of the site, might not amount to any more than a few extra views.

Additionally you might attract negative attention to your question. I would not be surprised at all if there were people who are more likely to upvote and/or answer visually flawless posts and more likely to downvote posts ridden with typos and grammatical mistakes. This effect might more than make up for the extra views from any potential bumps rendering all your sneaky efforts counterproductive.

*If you repeatedly roll back edits that correct formatting or typos, either your own or community edits, your motive will be clear that you are just trying to bump your question, and that will **certainly** be looked upon with a negative light, both by users and moderators.

There is nothing inherently wrong with bumping a question but try to make every edit count.